# How to set Flex application to open in browser windows

Tags: apache-flex

It's realy a silly question but I don't want to waste time looking for it.
The things is, I've build an application in flex which suppose to be for web but when I'm running it through the Flash builder, it opens up flash player app instead of openning in a web browser. I've tried to do "run as webapplication" but failed.
What should I do?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most likely you do not have a browser set up in Flash Builder; but rather have it specified to use the setand alone player.

Bring up Window => preferences and type Browser.  You'll see "General => Web browser"  .  What is selected?  Are any web browsers installed on your machine listed there?

You can add new browsers by selecting the "new" button and providing the location of the executable file which launches the browser.

Comment: Yes, I told it to use Firefox as external browser (which I installed there) and didnt work

Comment: In the flex website, it says that running a flex application should run in web browser by auto but it doesn't for me, it opens a flash player

Comment: I don't know what "In the Flex Website" refers to.  It sounds like you have a configuration issue somewhere, but I'm not sure what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Configure your debug configuration in order to launch html with your swf, but not swf itself: Run -> Debug Configurations -> URL or path to launch.

You can write html page yourself (alternatively - specify URL of your site), or you can set up autogenerating: Project -> Properties -> Flex Compiler -> Generate HTML wrapper file. After the last one your debug configuration will be changed automatically.